# Equivalent of policy.xml file with GraphicsMagick to deal with pixel flood DOS attack

Tags: security, graphicsmagick

Some of the vulnerabilities with ImageMagick are addressed by use of the policy.xml file. I would like to know if I can do the same thing with GraphicsMagick.

In particular, consider the [pixel flood attack exploit](https://hackerone.com/reports/390). This exploit involves specifying an extremely large pixel value in the encoding of the (small/regular sized) image itself, so that when the decoder tries to allocate memory for the entire image, it takes up all the memory and results in a dos attack. It was reported for a different app (paperclip) but the same technique easily applies to ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick.

ImageMagick [recommends avoiding this sort of attack via the policy.xml](https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=26020) file. How should one deal with this issue in GraphicsMagick? Or is GraphicsMagick somehow immune to this? Please explain.

Comment: `@Yogesch` I use ImageMagick extensively. I know that GraphicsMagick was an early offshoot of ImageMagick. Thus I had questioned if you had checked for an equivalent policy.xml file, since they were similar. Other than that I know little about GraphicsMagick. I only commented and did not try to answer the question as I was only qualified in a limited way. I did not mark your question down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GraphicsMagick does not have or recognize a policy.xml file.

In order to do things like set the maximum amount of memory, etc. one can set the environment variables of the software. Running the command `gm convert -list resources` will show an overview of the current allocations, in a format as below:

```
Resource Limits (Q16, 64 bits/pixel, 64bit address)
 Disk:  Unlimited (MAGICK_LIMIT_DISK)
Files:        256 (MAGICK_LIMIT_FILES)
  Map:    15.6GiB (MAGICK_LIMIT_MAP)
Memory: 7.8GiB (MAGICK_LIMIT_MEMORY)
Pixels: Unlimited (MAGICK_LIMIT_PIXELS)
Threads: 4 (OMP_NUM_THREADS)
Width: 256.0MiP (MAGICK_LIMIT_WIDTH)
Height: 256.0MiP (MAGICK_LIMIT_HEIGHT)
```

The terms in bold at the end denote the name of the actual environment variable, which can be set by issuing a command like `env MAGICK_LIMIT_MEMORY=200mb`

Source: [discussion on the GraphicsMagick forum](https://sourceforge.net/p/graphicsmagick/discussion/250737/thread/cbb86299/)